# Problem transforming data in the field into a tag

Tags: angular

```
validateBeforeSubmit(value: Object) {
    const _value = { ...value };
    if (this.field.dataType === FieldType.Tag && _value) {
      let newValue = '';
      _value[this.field.field].forEach((el, idx) => {
        if (idx > 0) {
          newValue += ',' + el;
        } else {
          newValue += el;
        }
      });
      _value[this.field.field] = newValue;
    }
    return _value;
  }
```

when I type a value in the field it only turns into a TAG after I click enter, I wanted to make it so that when a FocusOut of the field occurs it completes the tags..

There is a modal that I click on save, but it only accepts when it is a tag and this happens after clicking on enter.
I wanted to know a way of when the focusOut of the field occurs the value of the field is already transformed into tags.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iALwW.jpg)

Comment: If your field supports it, you could try to execute the method on the `blur` event: `(blur)="validateBeofreSubmit($event)"`

Comment: unsuccessfully. I just wanted the value to be transformed into a tag without needing to enter.

Comment: Why does the comment from @MikeS. not work? It works for me!

Comment: If the user writes something, in the "on leave" event of the field, invoke the same method of transforming the text into a chip as happens when pressing enter. Another option is to invoke this method on the form's save button as well. I would stick with the first idea because the change would be in the scope of the component.
I was thinking
the leave in the component, without giving the enter
could even clear the field, as if nothing had been told
Then, as this field is not mandatory, the treatment would be a common treatment of an empty non-mandatory field.